# Scraping specific text form webpage

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to scrape some graphs from a web page but I am new at this and don't know the best solutions.

```
<font color="DarkBLUE">
g:=Graph&lt;5|{ {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 5}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}, {2,
5}, {3, 4} }&gt;;</font>
```

What I need is the part `g:=Graph<..>`.
Here is what I tried until now (basing it in some other similar questions):

```
tree = lh.fromstring(data)
rate = tree.xpath("//font[@color='DarkBLUE']")
graphurls.append(rate[0].text_content())
```

But the problem is that there are a lot of other things that it scrapes. I think it can be done since it has a unique pattern `g:=Graph<...>` so nothing else gets scraped.

Can you help me?

Comment: `if text.strip().startswith("g:=Graph"): print(text.strip()[8:-2])` ?

Comment: _But the problem is that there are a lot of other things that it scrapes._ What other things? Please show the output, especially since you haven't shared a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First method:** you have string so you can use string's functions to filter results - ie.

```
if text.strip().startswith('g:=Graph') :
```

Example:

```
data = '''<font color="DarkBLUE">
g:=Graph&lt;5|{ {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 5}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}, {2,
5}, {3, 4} }&gt;;</font>

<font color="DarkBLUE">h:=Other&lt;...&gt;;</font>'''

import lxml.html as lh

tree = lh.fromstring(data)
rate = tree.xpath("//font[@color='DarkBLUE']")

for item in rate:
    text = item.text_content()
    text = text.strip()
    if text.startswith('g:=Graph'):
        print(' OK:', text)
    else:
        print('NOT:', text)
```

**Second method:** you can use `xpath` to filter it

```
tree.xpath("//font[@color='DarkBLUE' and contains(text(), 'g:=Graph')]")
```

or

```
tree.xpath("//font[@color='DarkBLUE'][contains(text(), 'g:=Graph')]")
```

Example:

```
data = '''<font color="DarkBLUE">
g:=Graph&lt;5|{ {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 5}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}, {2,
5}, {3, 4} }&gt;;</font>

<font color="DarkBLUE">h:=Other&lt;...&gt;;</font>'''

import lxml.html as lh

tree = lh.fromstring(data)
rate = tree.xpath("//font[@color='DarkBLUE' and contains(text(), 'g:=Graph')]")

for item in rate:
    text = item.text_content()
    text = text.strip()
    print(text)
```

Eventually with `starts-with()` but text in data is in new line so text in xpath needs `\n` at start

```
tree.xpath("//font[@color='DarkBLUE' and starts-with(text(), '\ng:=Graph')]")
```

---

**BTW:** [xpath cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/xpath)

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using a regular expression https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html, you can use https://regex101.com/ to experiment until you find the right formula

specifically, you can use capture groups `(\{\d+,\s*\d+\},?\s*)+` to find the repeating sequence of

"{2, 3}, {4, 5}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 5}, {1, 4}, {2, 4}, {3, 5},..."

I re-read your question, and you might have already known all of that, but you can use the regular expression in beautiful soup as well https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression

Answer (score 1):

One way is via `regex`:

```
import re

graphs=re.findall("g:=.*;;", rate[0].text_content())
```

This captures all matches starting with "g:=" and ending with ";;". It looks for such matches in string `rate[0].text_content()`.

**Note:**
Apply this to strings i.e. `.text_content()`, NOT to raw HTML.